# Azure DevOps - use ARM Outputs in ARM template parameters

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy a Virtual Network, Log analytics workspace and a Kubernetes service on Azure with Azure Devops.

The deployment of the Kubernetes Service requires input of my Log Analytics workspaceID and subnetID.
I can use the ARM Outputs task to get the outputs of these resources but how would I set them in my parameter file?

I know you can use linked templates for this but it requires a storage account which adds extra complexity.

Comment: I know it is not the direct answer to your question but have you considered using Terraform? Much simpler than ARM templates and is built into Cloud Shell bash shell. What you are trying to do is very easy when using Terraform.

Comment: I am willing to invest some time in it but there are so many IaC tools that I'm not sure which one is "the best"

Comment: Here is a decent article on CI/CD: https://open.microsoft.com/2018/05/22/cicd-azure-terraform-ansible-vsts-java-springboot-app/

Comment: did you already find a solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

you dont actually need to set them in the parameters file or parameters themselves. you can just get outputs from previous deployments to the resource group if you know their name(s).

But honestly, most likely you should deploy everything (related to the same app) under the same template (set of templates) so this is more of a self imposed issue. You can also just use arm template outputs and use outputs as input to other templaes